# General Entry Ledger for MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

hey there guys I'm having trouble with my ledger  I want my ledger to flexible like this any idea how to do it thanks.

expected output [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXEvb.jpg

This is my query:

```
SELECT drvYourTable.TransDate,drvYourtable.explination, drvYourTable.DrAmount, drvYourTable.CrAmount, (Select sum(Nz(DrAmount, 0) - Nz(CrAmount, 0))
        From tblYourtable
        Where tblYourtable.TransDate <= drvYourtable.TransDate
    ) AS Balance
FROM tblYourTable AS drvYourTable;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because *ms-access* didn't support *Windows function*

You can write a subquery in `select` clause to calculate `balance` column.

- `SUM(IIF(Debit IS NOT NULL,Debit,0))` Representing accumulated
- `SUM(IIF(Credit IS NOT NULL,-Credit,0))`  Cumulative reduction

that calculation by a condition `t1.DATE <= t.DATE`.

```
 select t.*,(
          SELECT SUM(IIF(Debit IS NOT NULL,Debit,0))+
                 SUM(IIF(Credit IS NOT NULL,-Credit,0))
          FROM SomeTable  t1 
          WHERE t1.DATE <= t.DATE
         ) as balance
from SomeTable t
```

Because there is no online ms-access, I use online sql-server as an example. This SQL can be run in ms-access.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/43a35/2)

Comment: I believe the only thing that's not valid about the SQL is the `from T t`, Access isn't case-sensitive, so that's a circular alias which is not valid. It's a bit nitpicky, but you might want to make it more explicit by using `from SomeTable t`